# Ember Power Select - How to close select of EPS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-addon

I'm trying to close the select box before it executes the search with Ember Power Select. I'm assuming the user knows what he is looking for if he paste a list and automatically sets the selected items.

I tried to use `select.actions.close()` but it seems that it is related to the onClose() event. I also try to use the property `opened` but changing it did not show any difference.

My component

```
{{#power-select-multiple
        renderInPlace=true
        search=(action "mySearch")
        selected=selected_item
        onchange=(action (mut selected_item))
        oninput=(action "checkPastingMultipleElements")
        opened=checkSelect
        as |name|
}}
    {{name}}
{{/power-select-multiple}}
```

my action

```
checkPastingMultipleElements(text, select) {
        this.set('selecteded_item', [text]);
        // error
        // select.actions.close()

        // does nothing
        // if (text.length === 4) { this.set('checkSelect', false); }            

        return false; // if true, it executes the search
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial guess was right, using `select.actions.close` is possible, but you have to enqueue this in the runloop to avoid a double-render problem.

Also, if what you want to do is to select a value and close the select, `select.actions.choose` is exactly what you want.

```
  checkPastingMultipleElements(text, select) {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('actions', null, select.actions.choose, [text]);
  }
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for developing this incredible addon. Second, thanks for the answer it led me to the right answer. The reason I needed to use `close()` is because I have to split the text in multiple choices and not only one. This way I could do `this.set('selected_item', text.split(" "));`

Comment: Also, I noticed that with the original answer (using choose), it throws an error whenever I delete the text `"Assertion Failed: \`{{power-select-multiple}}\` requires a \`searchField\` when the options are not strings to remove options using backspace"`.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. By example `{{power-select-multiple searchField="name"}}`. This made me realise that the documentation doesn't mention this. I should update it.